How to add draggable to DataTable component in PrimeVue
I created tree structure using DataTable from prime vue (https://tailwind.primevue.org/datatable/)
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <DataTable :value="visibleRows" dataKey="data.id" class="elements-list">
      <Column>
        <template #body="slotProps">
          <div
            :style="{
              paddingLeft: slotProps.data.level * 20 + 'px',
              display: 'flex',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }"
            class="expandable-row"
          >
            <span
              v-if="hasChildren(slotProps.data)"
              class="expander-icon"
              @click="toggleRow(slotProps.data)"
            >
              <i
                :class="[
                  'pi',
                  expandedRows[slotProps.data.data.id]
                    ? 'pi-chevron-down'
                    : 'pi-chevron-right',
                ]"
              ></i>
            </span>
            <span v-else style="width: 1em"></span>
            <Element
              :element-id="slotProps.data.data.id"
            />
          </div>
        </template>
      </Column>
    </DataTable>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, computed, watch, defineProps } from "vue";
import Element from "./Element.vue";
import DataTable from "primevue/datatable";
import Column from "primevue/column";

const props = defineProps({
  elements: {
    type: Array as () => any[],
    required: true,
    default: () => [],
  },
  expanded: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: false,
    default: false,
  },
});

const expandedRows = ref({});
const hasChildren = (rowData) => {
  return rowData.data.childElements && rowData.data.childElements.length > 0;
};
const toggleRow = (rowData) => {
  const id = rowData.data.id;
  if (expandedRows.value[id]) {
    delete expandedRows.value[id];
  } else {
    expandedRows.value[id] = true;
  }
};
const flattenTree = (elements, level = 0) => {
  let result = [];
  elements.forEach((element) => {
    result.push({
      data: element,
      level: level,
    });
    const isExpanded = expandedRows.value[element.id];
    if (isExpanded && element.childElements && element.childElements.length > 0) {
      const children = flattenTree(element.childElements, level + 1);
      result = result.concat(children);
    }
  });
  return result;
};
const visibleRows = computed(() => {
  return flattenTree(props.elements);
});
watch(
  () => props.expanded,
  () => {
    if (props.expanded) {
      expandAllNodes(props.elements);
    } else {
      expandedRows.value = {};
    }
  }
);
const expandAllNodes = (nodes) => {
  nodes.forEach((node) => {
    expandedRows.value[node.id] = true;
    if (node.childElements && node.childElements.length > 0) {
      expandAllNodes(node.childElements);
    }
  });
};
if (props.expanded) {
  expandAllNodes(props.elements);
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.elements-list {
  .p-datatable-tbody > tr > td {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .expandable-row {
    padding: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .expander-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
  }
}
</style>

It is not the result of my code but imagine I have a structure like this and I want to add drag and drop option into this component.

So each Element should be wrapped with draggable so that they can be drag and drop anywhere. I tried vuedraggable (https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable?ref=madewithvuejs.com) for it but it didnt work at all.
Could you please help me?

Do you want to implement drag-and-drop functionality to reorder rows within the table?

you can check this .

@Nilesh yes. So in the picture that I shared,'Applications' row is an element. Same with 'Vue' and 'editor.app' and 'settings.app'. So I want to reorder them with drag and drop functionality.

Using TreeTable, you can achieve this. In the body slot, you need to write custom logic for drag-and-drop. If need help let me know.

Here I tried with custom logic in the Primevue TreeTable slot As there is no props for reOrder.
Here is the stackBlitz link fo the same


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vue TreeTable with Drag-and-Drop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/primevue/resources/primevue.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/primeicons/primeicons.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/umd/primevue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/umd/treetable/treetable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/umd/column/column.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script>
        const { ref, onMounted } = Vue;
        const TreeTable = PrimeVue.TreeTable;
        const Column = PrimeVue.Column;

        const App = {
            components: {
                TreeTable,
                Column
            },
            setup() {
                const nodes = ref([
                    {
                        key: '0',
                        data: { name: 'Applications', size: '100kb', type: 'Folder' },
                        children: [
                            {
                                key: '0-0',
                                data: { name: 'Vue', size: '25kb', type: 'Folder' },
                                children: [
                                    { key: '0-0-0', data: { name: 'vue.app', size: '10kb', type: 'Application' } },
                                    { key: '0-0-1', data: { name: 'native.app', size: '10kb', type: 'Application' } },
                                    { key: '0-0-2', data: { name: 'mobile.app', size: '5kb', type: 'Application' } }
                                ]
                            },
                            { key: '0-1', data: { name: 'editor.app', size: '25kb', type: 'Application' } },
                            { key: '0-2', data: { name: 'settings.app', size: '50kb', type: 'Application' } }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        key: '1',
                        data: { name: 'Cloud', size: '20kb', type: 'Folder' },
                        children: [
                            { key: '1-0', data: { name: 'backup-1.zip', size: '10kb', type: 'Zip' } },
                            { key: '1-1', data: { name: 'backup-2.zip', size: '10kb', type: 'Zip' } }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        key: '2',
                        data: { name: 'Desktop', size: '150kb', type: 'Folder' },
                        children: [
                            { key: '2-0', data: { name: 'note-meeting.txt', size: '50kb', type: 'Text' } },
                            { key: '2-1', data: { name: 'note-todo.txt', size: '100kb', type: 'Text' } }
                        ]
                    }
                ]);

                const columns = ref([
                    { field: 'name', header: 'Name', expander: true },
                    { field: 'size', header: 'Size' },
                    { field: 'type', header: 'Type' }
                ]);

                const draggedNode = ref(null);

                const onDragStart = (event, node) => {
                    draggedNode.value = node;
                    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
                };

                const onDragOver = (event) => {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
                };

                const onDrop = (event, dropNode) => {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if (draggedNode.value && draggedNode.value !== dropNode) {
                        // Find and remove the dragged node
                        const removeNode = (nodes, node) => {
                            for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                                if (nodes[i] === node) {
                                    return nodes.splice(i, 1)[0];
                                }
                                if (nodes[i].children) {
                                    const result = removeNode(nodes[i].children, node);
                                    if (result) return result;
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        const dragged = removeNode(nodes.value, draggedNode.value);

                        // Find the parent of the drop node
                        const findParent = (nodes, node) => {
                            for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                                if (nodes[i].children && nodes[i].children.includes(node)) {
                                    return nodes[i];
                                }
                                if (nodes[i].children) {
                                    const result = findParent(nodes[i].children, node);
                                    if (result) return result;
                                }
                            }
                            return null;
                        };

                        const parentNode = findParent(nodes.value, dropNode);

                        // Insert the dragged node at the drop location within the same level
                        if (parentNode) {
                            const dropIndex = parentNode.children.indexOf(dropNode) + 1;
                            parentNode.children.splice(dropIndex, 0, dragged);
                        } else {
                            const dropIndex = nodes.value.indexOf(dropNode) + 1;
                            nodes.value.splice(dropIndex, 0, dragged);
                        }
                    }
                    draggedNode.value = null;
                };

                return {
                    nodes,
                    columns,
                    onDragStart,
                    onDragOver,
                    onDrop
                };
            },
            template: `
                <div class="card">
                    <TreeTable :value="nodes" tableStyle="min-width: 50rem">
                        <Column v-for="col of columns" :key="col.field" :field="col.field" :header="col.header" :expander="col.expander">
                            <template #body="slotProps">
                                <div
                                    draggable="true"
                                    @dragstart="(event) => onDragStart(event, slotProps.node)"
                                    @dragover="onDragOver"
                                    @drop="(event) => onDrop(event, slotProps.node)"
                                >
                                    {{ slotProps.node.data[col.field] }}
                                </div>
                            </template>
                        </Column>
                    </TreeTable>
                </div>
            `
        };

        Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app');
    </script>
</body>
</html>




Thanks for your answer @Nilesh but I see that I cannot drag and drop to upper level with your solution either.

You want the reordering to remain at the same level, correct? We won't make it nested.

I want the element can be drag and drop in any level. For example if the element is in the level 3 it can be dragged to level 1 or level 6, so anywhere should be possible

I edited the answer please check & confirm it.
